# ghexのビルドでgailというものがなく失敗する

Tags: ubuntu, build, gnome

ghexというバイナリエディタのアプリケーションをソースからビルドできないのです。
以下のエラーでビルドできないのです。

```
Dependency gail-3.0 not found
```

ところがこのgail-3.0が何なのかわからないのです。
Ubuntuのpackagesを探しても存在せず、代わりにlibgail, libatk, libatk-adapterなどををインストールしてもエラーは解決しませんでした。

OSはVirtualBox上でUbuntu 19.10を使用しています。

Comment: `sudo apt build-dep ghex` を実行すると、build に必要なパッケージを全てインストールしてくれます。

Comment: @metropolis このコマンドを実行すると私の環境だとsource URIが必要というエラーが出ますね
`You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list`

Comment: おそらく、`/etc/apt/sources.list` の内、`# deb-src ...` となっている行のコメント(`#`)を削除する必要があります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ghex に関しては [Ubuntu 向けのパッケージ](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/ghex) も提供されていますので念のため。

自分でコンパイルを行うのであれば、[libgail-3-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/libgail-3-dev) も必要になりそうな気がします。